# What are some ways of controlling moisture in the crawlspace?

Tags: moisture, crawlspace

I live in Los Angeles. I have a vented crawlspace.  The vents are about 6" x 15" or so.  I have about one every 6' or so along the walls of the house. The floor of the crawlspace is dirt.

I eventually want to insulate the crawl space. I've read that if I insulate the crawlspace, the insulation may hold onto moisture that may develop in the crawlspace. So, as a first step, I need to get the moisture levels under control before I insulate.

My question is what are some ways of controlling moisture in the crawlspace?

I've read that the dirt can be a source of moisture, so putting down polyethylene sheeting on the floor is one step to minimizing moisture.

I've also read that since I have vents, during warm days the temperature difference between the outside and the crawlspace potentially can cause condensation in the crawlspace wall.

I've also read that I should not close up the vents b/c that would prevent air flow which would then trap moisture.

There are so many things to consider and I can't figure out what is the right technique.